# How could I secure a PHP messaging system from spam?

Tags: php, spam, spam-prevention

I am currently creating a PHP messaging system and cannot seem to think of a suitable way to stop spam attacks. A message will be sent from this form (simplified to contain essentials):

```
<form action="messages/send" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="message" />
  <input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="10" />
  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

The hidden field above stores the recipient ID. This data is NOT secure on this site and is available for people to see (such as facebook; profile.php?id=45345345.)

When the form is submitted the back-end PHP does the following checks:

1. Is the sender logged in?
2. Is the send allowed to contact the recipient?
3. Does the message contain anything? (Not empty)

The problem I have thought of is someone could easily create a simple script which could auto increment the "recipient" value in the form and essentially send a site-wide message. What other back-end PHP checks, or other types of checks, could be carried out to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Add a captcha, a random generated small text to write before sending your form. This will avoid non expected runs from scripts.

Comment: Store the recipient value in the users session instead of on the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a few things:

- CSRF
- Server side and client side validation
- captcha - [http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/03/04/in-search-of-the-perfect-captcha/]
- [The Roboo script](http://www.ecl-labs.org/2011/03/17/roboo-http-mitigator.html). Demoed at Blackhat this year and gives you some DOS protection as well.
- Adding a honeypot hidden field that should never be completed. You
  can use Javascript to fill this in automatically on legitimate form
  submissions and validate server side.
- Velocity measures such as how fast the form is submitted.

Take a look at - https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4235/how-should-i-secure-a-contact-form-that-appears-on-every-page-of-a-website